# Improving row estimates for query with jsonb_object_keys()

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(json) AS key,
       json
FROM (
       SELECT json_object -> 'some_key' AS json
       FROM my_json_table
     ) j;
```

The planner currently estimates 100 rows to be returned by the `jsonb_object_keys` call for each from the inner query. In my case, it's 2. Since this underlies some larger queries in my database, it's critical that I get a better row estimate.

I would like to avoid creating a materialized view. Is there another approach to improve the query plan?

Comment: In general set-returning functions shouldn't be used in the SELECT list. Does this get better if you use `select k.* from my_json_table cross join jsonb_object_keys(json_object -> 'some_key') as k`

Comment: Unfortunately no, still estimates 100 rows. Also, `k` contains only the keys, so I would have to duplicate the json column logic for get the full result. (`select k, json_object -> 'some_key' from ...`). Is there another advantage to avoiding SRF in the SELECT?

Comment: Functions are (mostly) black boxes for the optimizer, and it will estimate a constant value that was specified in function definition.

Answer (score 1):

A super-user can do:

```
alter function jsonb_object_keys ( jsonb) rows 2;
```

But this will change the estimate for all uses of jsonb_object_keys in that database, not just that one use of it.

If you don't like that, you could duplicate the function and change the duplicate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_object_keys2(jsonb)
 RETURNS SETOF text
 LANGUAGE internal
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT ROWS 2
AS $function$jsonb_object_keys$function$;
```

Comment: Neat trick.. unfortunately, this would have too many side-effects in my case. And while it's 2 rows in this particular instance and table, that number isn't set in stone. I was hoping perhaps there'd be a way to reformulate the query, or create an index that helps. For example, the index `CREATE INDEX ON my_json_table ((json_object -> 'some_key'));` helps the inner query get a proper row estimate.

Comment: @maciej I don't think any index or reformulation is going to help to fix this automatically.  The addition of function-support-functions could allow you to add something, but I don't know where that something would get its estimate from, other than supplying it manually.  In principle perhaps it could use the values in the MCV and histogram bounds for the column stats, the same way commit a80818605e5447b9b846 (to be release in v13) does for the @> and ? operators, but that would not be trivial to implement.